Does every ring have a set's worth of simple modules?
Over certain kinds of rings, i.e. Artinian rings, there are only finitely many simple modules up to isomorphism. What can we say about simple modules over general rings? In particular, do the isomorphism classes of simple modules always form a set?
This question came up when I was trying to take an intersection indexed by the simple modules over a ring $\Lambda$. I was a bit worried since I am not sure if this intersection is well-defined if the collection of (isomorphism classes of) simple $\Lambda$-modules don't form a set.
Thank you very much for your help.

Yes. Simple $R$-modules are always cyclic, so always have the form $R/I$ where $I$ is a maximal left ideal. So the number of isomorphism classes is bounded by the number of subsets of $R$.
This bound is tight for infinite rings. If $X$ is any infinite set then the polynomial ring $\mathbb{F}_2[X]$ in one indeterminate for every $x \in X$ has the same cardinality as $X$ and has at least $|2^X|$ simple modules given by the $|2^X|$ homomorphisms $\mathbb{F}_2[X] \to \mathbb{F}_2$ (hence this is exactly the number of simple modules, but there are others besides these).
